# Save Informations and keep them when refreshing

Tags: javascript

still a beginner with JS and programming. I made a quick simple To-Do List, and now I'd like to keep the tasks displayed when I refresh the page. I read and watched tutorials about localStorage but I haven't been able to do what I  want yet. When I use it, data is well saved but it doesn't stay on the page when I refresh.

Here is my code:

NB: I removed localStorage from it for now so there is no "tests" in the code. What's left is only what's functionnal at the moment!

HTML:

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tdl3.css">
    <title>To-Do List 3.0</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>To-do List</h1>
        <input type="text" id="taskInput" placeholder="Ajouter une tâche...">
        <button id="taskButton">Ajouter</button>
    </div>
    </header>

    <div id="list">
        
    </div>
    

<script src="tdl3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    src: url('polices2/quicksand/Quicksand-Regular.otf');
}

body {
    font-family: Quicksand;
}

#header {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 450px;
}

input {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid darkslategray;
    font-family: Quicksand;
}

button {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-family: Quicksand;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    color:white;
}

button:hover {
    color: darkslategrey;
    background-color: white;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

p {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 450px;
}

#list button {
    color: white;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#list button:hover {
    color: darkslategrey;
    background-color: white;
}

#list p {
    font-size: bold;
}
```

JS:

```
let button = document.getElementById("taskButton");

//EVENT LISTENER
button.addEventListener("click", addTask);

//FONCTIONS
function addTask() {
    let input = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;
    let newTask = document.createElement('p');
    let checkBtn = document.createElement('button');
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
    newTask.innerHTML = `${input}`;
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newTask);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(checkBtn);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(deleteBtn);

    checkBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        newTask.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    });

    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        newTask.style.display = "none";
        checkBtn.style.display = "none";
        deleteBtn.style.display = "none";
    });
};
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: You need to save the data at an appropriate time, and then also have code which (again at the moment of your choosing) checks if any data already exists in the storage, and loads it back into the page again. If you have a problem with your storage code, you need to show it to us so we can help you fix it. Showing working but irrelevant code is not much use to use in helping you, and we are not going to re-write your whole storage feature for you from the beginning, that's not what this site is about.

Comment: See also [ask] and how to produce a [mre] of your issue, and try again. You can [edit] your question when you're ready. N.B. I'd suggest that your CSS code is not at all relevant to the issue at hand, since reading and writing data into storage doesn't depend on any display or layout factors.

Comment: @ADyson they said this: NB: I removed localStorage from it for now so there is no "tests" in the code. What's left is only what's functionnal at the moment!

Comment: @ericmp actually I also just read that and added an extra bit to my comment. As I've said above now, that isn't at all helpful for us trying to assist, they need to show the code with the problem, not some other code which doesn't have a problem.

Comment: You need to show us your attempt at using local storage - it's most likely when you read it back out that you are not putting it back into the dom at that point

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you a simple example, so you can figure out how to store it in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and how to retrieve it:

```html
<input id="addTaskInput" />

<button id="addTaskBtn">Add task</button>

<ul id="tasksList"></ul>

<script defer>
// get DOM elements
const addTaskInput = document.querySelector('#addTaskInput')
const addTaskBtn = document.querySelector('#addTaskBtn')
const tasksList = document.querySelector('#tasksList')

// function to append a task to the tasklist
const appendTaskToList = taskTxt => {
  let myLi = document.createElement('li')
  myLi.textContent = taskTxt
  tasksList.appendChild(myLi)
}

// when the page loads, get the tasks from the storage or set them as an empty array
let tasks = []

if (localStorage.getItem('tasks')) {
  tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'))

  for (const task of tasks) {
    appendTaskToList(task)
  }
}

// when add task btn is clicked, push the task to list and save it in localStorage
addTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let task = addTaskInput.value

  tasks.push(task)

  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))

  appendTaskToList(task)

  addTaskInput.value = ``
})
</script>
```